# Tcl How to pass arguments to a proc

Tags: tcl

I am new to TCL and having tough times to call a 3rd part proc which works perfectly if we pass values like below:

```
set result [3RD_par_api {{ifAdminStatus.2 Integer 1}}]
puts $result
```

Where ifAdminStatus.2 is an OID [SNMP Object Identifier] and Integer is datatype and value to be set is 1.

The code works fine but when I try to do using my script variables:

```
set result [3RD_par_api {{$id $data $val}}]
puts $result
```

I get error -

> "illegal binding ...$id $data $val"

How can I pass user defined / variables as arguments to 3RD_par_api method and what does argument in double braces means "{{ }}"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at the differences.  With a single set a braces, Tcl treats the
argument as a single word (in some ways similar to single quotes in other languages).
But if you access it as a list, it gets broken up into multiple pieces:

```
foreach elem {ifAdminStatus.2 Integer 1} {
   puts $elem
}

ifAdminStatus.2
Integer
1
```

And with doubled braces:

```
foreach elem {{ifAdminStatus.2 Integer 1}} {
   puts $elem
}

ifAdminStatus.2 Integer 1
```

The list now contains a single argument: "ifAdminStatus.2 Integer 1".

To create a list, use the `list` command:

```
# this is the same as {ifAdminStatus.2 Integer 1}
# it contains three strings
set arg [list ifAdminStatus.2 Integer 1]

# this is the same as {{ifAdminStatus.2 Integer 1}}
# it contains a single string
set arg [list {ifAdminStatus.2 Integer 1}]
```

Apparently the API wants a list with a single string as an argument.
To create this with variables, use the `list` command twice.

```
set id ifAdminStatus.2
set data Integer
set val 1
set arg [list [list $id $data $val]]
foreach elem $arg {
   puts $elem
}

ifAdminStatus.2 Integer 1
```

What you want to try is:

```
set result [3RD_par_api [list [list $id $data $val]]]
```

Or simply:

```
set result [3RD_par_api [list "$id $data $val"]]
```

Comment: No idea why the API would do things that way.  Makes life difficult.

Comment: Thanks a lot using "set result [3RD_par_api [list [list $id $data $val]]]" solved my problem. Thanks once again